# Installshield problem setting file permissions

Tags: windows, windows-10, installshield, installshield-2011

in InstallShield 2011, I cannot modify file permissions under Application Data -> Files and Folders. Whenever I right click on items, it shows grayed out menu buttons. I can't even delete existing entries.

[image]

In a bat script later in the installer, I can't copy over certain files because I don't have the right permissions so the installer fails when trying to reference files in BackupFiles. For some reason all the other files get copied over just fine; I can't modify those file's permissions either. I read online that you have to click the "Properties" button in that context menu to change permissions.

My version is InstallShield 2011 Premiere Edition Version 17.

I don't understand why this is grayed out. The source files do not have any restrictions on them so it must be the installer doing something related to permissions.

Comment: Why do you need a .BAT file?

Answer (score 1):

That boxy orange overlay on the folders and files indicates that these are coming from a [Dynamic File Link](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpDynamicFileLinking.htm). Because these files aren't actually added to your project, not all configuration options are available. You might have to edit the permissions on the source files (before build), or change your project to statically include all or some of these files. Given the size of that tree, changing it all to static could be a bit tedious. Changing parts of it (by editing the link exclusions) might be a good middle ground.

Or you could better determine what's going wrong and see if you can address it in the batch file. Assuming this is InstallScript (rather than InstallScript MSI), the entire setup along with any processes it launches should be elevated. So I'm having a hard time guessing what could go wrong. Perhaps a read-only flag? Perhaps use a tool like process monitor to get more information on that, and see if you can add a call to attrib -r, or cacls, or whatever.